# QCheckBox word-wrap

Tags: qt, pyqt

Is there a way to wrap text in QCheckBox like it is done with QLabel?

```
label = QLabel( QString.fromUtf8('long text in here'))
label.setWordWrap(True)
```

I tried `\n` which will add a linebreak but this is not dynamic if I resize the window.

Comment: It seems there is a feature request for this at https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-5370. The issue is not closed, so likely this feature is not implemented.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839194/qcheckbox-qradiobutton-line-wrap-qt4-6-0) question, it has at least two options to use for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems there is a feature request for this at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-5370.

The issue is not closed, so likely this feature is not implemented. This means that it is not currently possible to add word wrap to QCheckBox.

You can try various workarounds, such as having an empty-text QCheckBox and a QLabel to the right, or try putting a shorter text for the checkbox, with a label below it with the long explanation.

Comment: Another solution would be to just use a tooltip.  The purpose of a tooltip is for describing in detail.  Unfortunately, many users are not familiar with looking for tooltips.

Comment: It's possible to implement this in a clean way by handling the `resizeEvent` within a custom `QCheckBox` subclass, and to perform the necessary line wrapping there. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

You can develop a [Custom widgets for QtDesigner](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html) to use this feature graphically (or not).

**[`CheckBoxWordWrap`](https://github.com/thibDev/qtCustomPlugins)** (dynamic when resize):

[image: CheckBoxWordWrap]

**In QtDesigner**:

[image: CheckBoxWordWrap plugin]
[image: CheckBoxWordWrap properties]

You can also use the class and modify it if the behavior is not exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

"This is my double **\n** line checkbox". Now you have double line checkbox

[image: Double Line Checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

There unfortunately is no short and simple solution for this. There's a Qt feature request about this (see [QTBUG-5370](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-5370)), but it's pending since 2009 (!), so it probably will never be implemented.

However, it's actually possible to implement this by overriding the `QCheckBox::resizeEvent` and to perform the necessary line wrapping there. In addition to that, we must also adjust the horizontal size policy and override the minimum size hint so that the layout of the check box will be correct.

The complete implementation is given below.

### LineWrappedCheckBox.h

```
#include <QCheckBox>

class LineWrappedCheckBox : public QCheckBox {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    void wrapLines(int width);
protected:
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
public:
    LineWrappedCheckBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : LineWrappedCheckBox(QString(), parent) { }
    LineWrappedCheckBox(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    virtual QSize minimumSizeHint() const { return QSize(QCheckBox().minimumSizeHint().width(), sizeHint().height()); }
};
```

### LineWrappedCheckBox.cpp

```
#include "LineWrappedCheckBox.h"
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QResizeEvent>
#include <QStyle>

void LineWrappedCheckBox::wrapLines(int width) {
    QString word, line, result;
    for (QChar c : text().replace('\n', ' ') + ' ') {
        word += c;
        if (c.isSpace()) {
            if (!line.isEmpty() && fontMetrics().width(line + word.trimmed()) > width) {
                result += line.trimmed() + '\n';
                line = word;
            } else {
                line += word;
            }
            word.clear();
        }
    }
    result += line.trimmed();
    setText(result.trimmed());
}

void LineWrappedCheckBox::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
    int controlElementWidth = sizeHint().width() - style()->itemTextRect(fontMetrics(), QRect(), Qt::TextShowMnemonic, false, text()).width();
    wrapLines(event->size().width() - controlElementWidth);
    QCheckBox::resizeEvent(event);
}

LineWrappedCheckBox::LineWrappedCheckBox(const QString &text, QWidget *parent) : QCheckBox(text, parent) {
    QSizePolicy policy = sizePolicy();
    policy.setHorizontalPolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred);
    setSizePolicy(policy);
    updateGeometry();
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "LineWrappedCheckBox.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    LineWrappedCheckBox checkBox("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.");
    checkBox.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

This will create a freely resizable window with a line wrapped check box in it:

[image: LineWrappedCheckBox screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Answering 10 years later but I got around this problem using a custom widget

```
class custom_checkbox(QCheckBox):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        text_label = QLabel()
        text_label.setText(text)
        text_label.setWordWrap(True)
    
        layout.addWidget(text_label)
  
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.mouse_inside = False
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.mouse_inside = True
    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouse_inside = True
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.mouse_inside:
            self.setChecked(not self.isChecked())
```

You will have to set custom css for the checkbow widget you create on your own otherwise it will look buggy

Here is the css I used for a checkbox widget named checkbox_widget

```
checkbox_widget.setStyleSheet(f"""
                        QCheckBox {{
                        background-color: {color};
                        color: white;
                        padding: 30px;
                        border-radius: 5px;
                        border : none
                        }}  
                        QCheckBox::indicator {{
                        image: none;
                        }}
                        QCheckBox::indicator:checked {{
                        image: none;
                        }}
                        QLabel {{
                        background-color : {color};
                        padding: 20px;
                        font-size: 20px
                        }}
                        """)
```

If you want the Indicator then remove the indicator css and change the padding-left value of the QLabel to about 40px, It should work fine

```
checkbox_widget.setStyleSheet(f"""
                       QCheckBox {{
                       background-color: {color};
                       color: white;
                       padding: 30px;
                       border-radius: 5px;
                       }}  
                       QCheckBox::indicator {{
                       subcontrol-position:left;
                       background-color: {color_for_unchecked_indicator};
                       border-radius: 4px;
                       }}
                       QCheckBox::indicator:checked {{
                       background-color: {color_for_checked_indicator};
                       }}
                       QLabel {{
                       padding-left: 40px;
                       }}
                       """)
```